# Properties based on $x^Tx=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are linearly independent and $x_1^Tx_1=1,\;x_2^Tx_2=1$. $X=[x_1,x_2]$. Let $Q=X^{-1}$ and let $q_i^T$ be $\textit{i}$th row of Q.

As it turns out $x_iq_i^T$ has a lot of properties:

1) $x_1q_1^T\cdot x_2q_2^T=x_2q_2^T\cdot x_1q_1^T0;\;\;$  $x_iq_i^T\cdot x_iq_i^T=1;$

2) $x_1q_1^T +x_2q_2^T=1;$

3) $X\left[\begin{matrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2 \end{matrix}\right]X^{-1}=\lambda_1x_1q_1^T+\lambda_2x_2q_2^T.$

To be honest I am still trying to figure out how to incorporate condition $x_i^Tx_i=1$.

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking us to prove those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write
$$
X = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2}; \quad 
X^{-1} = \pmatrix{q_1^T\\q_2^T}
$$
In order to prove 1) and 2), note that
$$
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} &=XX^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{x_1 & x_2} \pmatrix{q_1^T\\q_2^T} = x_1q_1^T + x_2q_2^T\\
&= X^{-1}X=
\pmatrix{q_1^T\\q_2^T} \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2} =
\pmatrix{
q_1^Tx_1 & q_2^Tx_2\\
q_2^T x_1 & q_2^T x_2
}
\end{align}
$$

For the third one, we have
$$
\begin{align}
X\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2 }X^{-1}&=
\pmatrix{x_1 & x_2}\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2 }\pmatrix{q_1^T\\q_2^T}
\\&=
\pmatrix{x_1 & x_2}\pmatrix{\lambda_1 q_1^T\\\lambda_2 q_2^T}
\\&=
\lambda_1x_1q_1^T+\lambda_2x_2q_2^T
\end{align}
$$
So far, as you have rightly noted, there has been no need to use the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ have length $1$. Similarly, you can show 3) by simply applying the rules of (block-) matrix multiplication. It doesn't seem that $x^Tx = 1$ makes any difference here.

If you are additionally given the fact that $x_1^T x_2 = 0$, then you actually have a very convenient way of computing $X^{-1}$.  Namely: under this condition, $X$ is an orthogonal matrix, which means that $X^{-1} = X^T$, which is to say that $q_i = x_i$.